# How do I use a unique Action URL for each Identity Platform tenant when generating email action links with the Firebase Admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

I'm using Google Cloud Platform's Identity Platform product in multi-tenancy mode. I have one GCP project with two web apps and each app has a tenant in Identity Platform:

- Tenant A with the tenant ID `tenant-a-1234` at a.example.com
- Tenant B with the tenant ID `tenant-b-5678` at b.example.com

I need to [generate password reset links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_password_reset_email_link) for users in these tenants. The Firebase Admin SDK generates links using [the Action URL that is defined in the Firebase console under Authentication > Templates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#link_to_your_custom_handler_in_your_email_templates). That works fine when it's vanilla Firebase with a single tenant but I'm using Identity Platform and multi-tenancy so I need an Action URL for each tenant so that links for Tenant A point to a.example.com and links for Tenant B point to b.example.com.

Here's an example of how I'm generating the links:

```js
let tenantId = 'tenant-b-5678';
let email = 'foo@b.example.com';

const auth = admin.auth().tenantManager().authForTenant(tenantId);
auth
    .generatePasswordResetLink(email)
    .then((resetUrl) => {
        console.log(resetUrl);
    });
```

`resetUrl` is forever stuck using [whatever domain name is set in the Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#link_to_your_custom_handler_in_your_email_templates) and it enforces this for all tenants in the project.

It's not feasible for me to have one [email action handler page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) that handles both tenants. Ideally, I would be able to call the Firebase API and pass in a custom Action URL to have the generated link use it. That doesn't appear possible.

One alternative would be to have my Cloud Function generate the link and then find and replace the domain name. I'd rather not maintain a static mapping of sites to tenant ids in my code, and it seems like this is something Identity Platform probably can do for me, so I'm hoping there's an alternative.

How do I use a unique Action URL for each Identity Platform tenant when generating email action links with the Firebase Admin SDK?

Comment: I found this [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-managing-tenants#generating_email_action_links) that actually might be what you are looking for, do you think this would work in your case?

Comment: That's the same sample code that is in my post. I use `admin.auth().tenantManager().authForTenant()` to make the call to generate the link. [actionCodeSettings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.ActionCodeSettings) doesn't apply. And the last code sample in that section is about handling the link in the client after it has been generated and the user has clicked it, while my problem is regarding link generation.